# How to add multiple sheets to an Excel workbook and save it (infinite loading)

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to add multiple empty sheets to a existing workbook,                  the langage is VB.net and the code is launched on a local server

The complete code :

```
Dim objApp As Excel.Application
Dim objBook As Excel._Workbook
Dim objBooks As Excel.Workbooks

objApp = New Excel.Application()
objApp.Visible = True
objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(MyPath)
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    objBook.Sheets.Add()
Next

objBook.Save()
objBook.Close()
objApp.Quit()
```

When the code is executed, the xls file is saved but no sheets have been added.
 And i have infinite loading with my localhost
 Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify if this is VBA code or VB.NET code and where this code is run. Is this the complete code or are there any `On Error Resume …` lines in your code?

Comment: Your code works fine. Did you check what kind of Excel is installed on your server? Maybe it is just Viewer.

Comment: Any reason why you used the interface here `Excel._Workbook` instead of `Excel.Workbook`? • Aso make sure that the file get's not opened in read only mode. Therefore make sure no other software is using that file (has it opened) at the same time.

Comment: I'm sure that is not viewer, because the other applications on the same server can write in xls files, i used Excel._WorkBook because i was inspired by the  other application of the server, and i killed all the process which used this excel file before i launch my code

Comment: You should provide more information. What version is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: I only know that the version of Microsoft Excel is the 2010 version

Comment: Did you try with different workbooks?

Comment: No, do you have recommandation ? I'm a newbie with this environment

Comment: @ImranKrimi Create a brand new empty workbook in the same folder. Name it `TEST1234` and use it's path and filename for `.Open(MyPath)` to check if it is an issue with your file or an issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine .....

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Dim objApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objBook As Excel._Workbook
    Dim objBooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        objApp = New Excel.Application()
        objApp.Visible = True
        objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
        objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("\\PC1\1.xlsx")
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            objBook.Sheets.Add()
        Next
        objBook.Save()
        objBook.Close()
        objApp.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just make the executable and then run it in the mode
Run as administrator
By pressing the right click program and then clicking on Run as administrator

Comment: Why would running it as administrator help here? Actually if the user had not the previlege to edit the file the `.Save()` command should fail I think. And actually working as administrator is a very bad practice. Instead give the user the privileges he needs.

Comment: I think that the file on the drive C almost in this case must be reached as an administrator, either if the file to any other drive like D will add sheets without problem

Comment: Even if that is the case you would give the user the previlege for that file/folder instead of running it as administrator. The absoulte **only** case where to use the administrator is to administrate the system and **never** use an administrator for working.

Comment: Some commands do not work in such cases as deleting a sheet, adding a sheet, deleting a row, adding a row and some other commands

Comment: No, if the user has the privileges to edit the file, then **everything** will work in Excel (including the commands you mentioned). Administator is for system administrating **only**. If you use it for working you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I tried the file and gave it full control, but it does not add sheets only using as administrator or move file to another drive

Comment: That cannot be either the file is accesible to write or not. Windows privileges can only allow/disallow write access to a file in general but it cannot disallow special commands in Excel. That is just not possible.

Comment: It actually works on c but in certain places away from system files

Comment: This is what happens. Try it. I do not know the exact reason, but this is what happens. Some commands do not work, knowing that it is the same code in all cases There is no error!!!!

Comment: Then you didn't set the privileges properly.

Comment: Maybe thanks for this discussion
I will see what can be done